# JS Bitwise Operator to Java

Tags: javascript, java, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to convert a js function to Java but i don't know how to work with JS Bitwise operator in java.

I need to translate this:

`var r = '0x' + a.substring(j, 2) | 0     and
('0x' + a.substr(j, 2) ^ r)`

Has anyone ever done that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `bitwise or` do on a string?

Comment: @byxor looks like it collapses its arguments to Number (defaults to 0), then apply the operation on these Numbers

Comment: Some weird collapsing rules though. `[1]` collapses to `1` and `[2]` to `2`, but `[1,2]` collapses to `0`. Maybe it is common knowledge to JS developers, but it sure feels weird.

Answer (score 3):

Java's bitwise operators are explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Basically ^ is XOR, & is AND and | is OR.

You can find the specification here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22

However they cannot be applied to strings (thank god!).

Answer (score 0):

First, separate the the string parsing and the bitwise operators into separate steps.

(Bjorn pointed out above; bitwise operators don't auto-cast in Java like they do in Javascript!)

So

```
'0x' + a.substring(j, 2)
```

Becomes :

```
 String foo = '0x' + a.substring(j, 2);
 int value = Integer.parseInt(foo, 16);
```

Which should take a base-16 number represented in a string, and move it to an int.   Once you've got it as an int, you can use Java bitwise operators just fine.